# Application to create visualization of system idea and architecture

Tags: visualization

I get a lot of ideas for applications and I write them down on paper and they often stays
there because I don't have any good application to visualize them digital.

Looking for a good way to draw flowcharts, components and communicationpaths, database structure etc.

Is there any good open source applications for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are lots of open source tools for drawing charts. [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia/) is a good example.